# How to implement Push Notification with Oracle in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oracle, github, push-notification

I'm struggling with Push Notification in iOS and it should be based on Oracle. Here is the link to the documentation provided by Oracle but there is a version difference between [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCFA/ios/step-by-step/) & [GitHub SDK](https://github.com/pushio/PushIOManager_iOS).

No matter to implement the feature on 6.29.1 or 6.31.0.
The document is based on 6.31.0 but the regarding github sdk is based on 6.29.1 alone.
I'm lost how to synchronize the SDK and the document with the version difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found [old documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E59511_02/) which syncs with github SDK version.

[UPDATED]

Oracle support team updated the documentation for old SDK as my request.

Answer (score 1):

I had experience in old versions You'd better to contact the support team of Oracle.